# Bootstrap Scrollspy is not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, scrollspy

I am trying to implement a fixed side menu that updates the active page link with the active class. I placed the scroll spy HTML5 elements on the body, but I am having issues. Can someone check out my page and see if they can determine what's wrong?

http://mattaltepeter.com/new/about.shtml

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The issue is that you have placed your nav inside a div and than using the nav id to the scroll. In order To make the scrollspy to work You can assign "side-nav" to the span3 div like :
Jsfiddle [demo in browser](http://jsfiddle.net/shail/4NPdY/2/show)

```
<div class="row">
<div class="span3" id="side-nav">
    <ul class="nav nav-list about-list hidden-phone hidden-tablet affix" >
        <li class="active"><a href="#about"><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i> About Me</a></li>
        <li><a href="#education"><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i> Education</a></li>
        <li><a href="#work"><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i> Work Experience</a></li>
        <li ><a href="#sports"><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i> Sports</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

You can create your para section in the following way :

```
<div class="page-header" id="about">
        <h1 >About Me</h1>

    <p>My name is Matt Altepeter. I am 21 years old .</p>
    </div>
```

Please remove the script to initialize scrolling , since you have already added them to body

```
<body data-offset="50" data-target="#side-nav" data-spy="scroll">
```

Its good practice to declare bootstrap.js just after the jquery and before any other script . Put all your script in footer , helps save loading time .

```
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Ah thank you. This got it to mostly work. The only issue now is when the page is loaded, the last item on the menu is highlighted by default even though I manually assign `class="active"` on the first item. Any suggestions?

Comment: The issue is in your script section the javascript you are using to add class active .

Comment: I deleted everything in the script tag except to initialize the scrollspy and it still sets the last nav item to active on page load.

Comment: on my jsfiddle its working .. there is something which is raising the issue

Comment: Thanks for the edits. Removing the jQuery to initialize scroll spy worked perfectly. Thanks again.

Comment: Thank you! Saved me some head banging not knowing why it wasn't working!